# How does nodejs usually manipulate DOM from the backend without using socket

Tags: javascript, node.js

Usually what I would do is

In backend

```
socket.emit("manipulate", data);
```

In frontend

```
socket.on("manipulate", data);
```

So that you can signal Jquery to manipulate the DOM in frontend

However because I want to manipulate the DOM in app.js where

FILES

```
app.js
backend.js
ui.js
```

app.js

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res){

  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/views/test.html');
  Backend.manipulate(req.body, function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err;
    // how do I manipulate DOM here
   });
});
```

backend.js

```
exports.listen = function(server){

    io = socketio.listen(server);
    io.set('log level', 2);
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    });
}
```

I don't have access to socket, and I can't move exports.listen as all my socket manipulation is there.

Any advice would be appreciated

Edit:

For clarification on the use case, say that I have a registration form in the front end, the registration is submit through POST, and POST calls a function in backend.js that register the user, after backend.js succesfully register the user it would like to send a message to the user, how would that message normally be display in frontend?

Comment: Nodejs has no concept of DOM unless you use a library like jsDOM, or [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio)

Comment: Thanks, are there any signalling functions like socket, where I can pass data to fronend UI?

Comment: I just checkout cheerio, I will give it a try, thanks for the recommendation

Comment: As far as i know they do not. Why not send the post through the socket? Then you would have your socket for doing manipulation and send back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am completely new to nodejs and webdev, so I wasn't sure if another socket in POST is going to interfere with the socket in backend.js, but I'll also give that a try, thanks

Comment: you need to connect to client side and tell it to do something and may provide more data. And to connect to client you could simply use ajax, socket, or server events.